# Selecting a bootstrap thumbnail by unique ID - jQuery returns "undefined"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a template for my thumbnails and I want to display a button inside the thumbnail if the ID in

```
<div id="product-id-{{product-id}}" class="product"> \
```

matches another ID comming from the backend.

For the purpose I am using this jQuery code :

```
var sPriceInDom = Number($("#product-id-"+sProductId+" .product-price").text());
```

The ID in the DOM looks like this - `#product-id-1475081924608`.

The idea is simple and in my head everything is working, but sadly the result from this jQuery code is `undefined` and I have no idea why.

Here is my thumbnail's template code :

```
var sProductTemplate = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> \
                                <div class="thumbnail"> \
                                <div id="product-id-{{product-id}}" class="product"> \
                                  <div class="caption"> \
                                    <h3>{{product-name}}</h3> \
                                    <div class="product-price">{{product-price}}</div> \
                                  </div> \
                                </div> \
                              </div>';
```

Please, help!

Comment: It feels like we need more details here: how are you filling this template? Ho does javascript know if ID matches, etc. ? Those details will help others better understand your issue.

Comment: Hey, @PavelKovalev!  I think i have provided the needed details. The problem is that my jQuery doesn't work and I think everything for that is in the template I pasted in my question. I have added an example of how the ID part in the template looks with an actual ID.

Comment: No worries, somebody is gonna help you. While you are waiting, you can mock you question using a tool like https://jsfiddle.net . Just a suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Jquery used to bind when the dom is loaded but in our case the code get executed after page loading . 
you can do like

```
var product_id = "{{product-id}}";
function select_product(product_id){
  return $('#product-id-'+product_id).find('.product-price').text();
}

// call this function using timmer 
select_product(product_id);
```